# Django RestFramework Serializer request.data with array object

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

i have this situation, i received by POST this data:

```
{'fields':[{'key':'comment', 'value':'something', 'data_type':'string'},
           {'key':'days', 'value':'2', 'data_type':'int'}]}
```

My serializers

```
class FieldSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    value = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
    data_type = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
    key = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)


class FieldsSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    fields = FieldSerializer(many=True)
```

In my view pass request.data to FieldsSerializer()

```
serializer = FieldsSerializer(data=request.data)
serializer.is_valid()
raise Exception(serializer.data, serializer.errors)
```

output:

> Exception: (ReturnDict([('fields', [])]), ReturnDict())

i use versions Django==1.8.15 and djangorestframework==3.0

Answer (score 0):

you has single data for your `FieldsSerializer`, so you just need to remove `many=True` while initial the serializer.

```
serializer = FieldsSerializer(data=request.data)
#                                          ^^^^^^
```

or as universal solution

```
many = isinstance(request.data, list)
serializer = FieldsSerializer(data=request.data, many=many)
```